# How can I model a railmotor roof?

Tags: modeling, bevel

G'day everyone,

Just trying to model the exact same railmotor and having trouble modelling the damn forsaken roof! I am using Blender 2.79b to make the model in

If someone could tell me how exactly to model the roof this would be great! I have used every method I can using the bevel but it's just problems with it overlapping or not doing what I want it to do

See here for photos of the railmotor and the roof I am really getting frustrated with
https://sites.google.com/site/queenslandgreattrains/Home/the-railmotors/1800-class-the-blue-lagoons

[image]

Comment: Hey !! It is always to show what you tried instead of directly asking about how to make it completely so that we can get an idea of where you are facing the issue. Please add some pic of your work and explain whats exactly going wrong

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes bevel is probably the tool to use, first bevel the front (probably more segments as you'll see later):

[image]

Then the sides:

[image]

Then create some inner loop cuts:

[image]

Extrude and flatten the top light:

[image]

[image]

Create additional edge loops in order to round it, etc (the proportions are not good of course):

[image]

When you'll bring the *Subdivision Surface* modifier you'll need more edge loops:

[image]

Comment: And that's probably the only thing I never tried! I didn't think to bevel the front first... THANKS HEAPS

Comment: @PhilChorusch I'd say as a general rule you should always bevel from large to small scale. Of course there might be exceptions and surely it depends on what exact look you are going for.

Comment: @PhilChorusch Hello and welcome. Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).